# Inserting jsonb data via PostgreSQL on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jsonb

I'm a newbie in backend development and just started to build a simple table including jsonb type with PostgreSQL in node.js on Ubuntu.

```
CREATE TABLE testTable ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, vStr VARCHAR(64), jVar jsonb);
```

Then I tried to insert a data as below.

```
const {Client} = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
  host: 'ip addr',
  user, database name, etc...
});
client.connect();

const strA = "test string A";
const a1 = 1;
const query = {
  text: `INSERT INTO testTable (id, vStr, jVar) VALUES (${a1}, ${strA}, '{"cnt":${a1}}')`
};
client.query(query).then(client.end()).catch( error handling... );
```

I used variables in query statement because I have to get values from parameters.

I ran

> node insertTestTable.js

but just saw

> error: syntax error at or near "string"

> at /MyWorkspace/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:526:17

> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I searched a lot in Google but failed to find a solution. Time is choking me, that's why I ask advices in stackoverflow because there're great engineers here.

I expected it's added in my database.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| id | 1 |
| vStr | "test string A" |
| jVar | {"cnt":1} |

===========================================

@Bergi, Could you please help once more?
What I wanted to was as below, more complex case.

```
const strA = "test string A";
const a1 = 1;
const pr = true;

const query = {
  text: "INSERT INTO testTable (id, vStr, jVar) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)",
  values: [a1, strA, JSON.stringify({pro:pr,es:[{name:strA,qr:a1}]})]
};
```

I ran this but got an error:

> error: syntax error at end of input

> at /MyWorksapce/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:526:17

> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: `.then(client.end())` should be `.finally(() => client.end())`

Comment: "*Could you please help once more?*" - you might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that, edits generally won't be seen (and also @-tagging only works in comments). But the problem appears to be that you use a `$4` parameter for which you pass no value

Answer (score 1):

You are generating the SQL text

```sql
INSERT INTO testTable (id, vStr, jVar) VALUES (1, test string A, '{"cnt":1}')
```

which is a syntax error. You'd need to escape the value as an SQL literal, however you should rather use a [parameterised query](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query):

```js
const query = {
  text: "INSERT INTO testTable (id, vStr, jVar) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)",
  values: [a1, strA, JSON.stringify({cnt: a1})],
};
```

Comment: Dear Bergi, thank you for your great answer! It's really effective.